# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function "React JS problem Facing While using a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

it has been almost 2 to 3 days trying to sought out this error but Don't know why im unable to resolve this error. :(
this is my first React project help me to get out of it
Tried almost every way to resolve this error
*Used function Home (props)
export default Home;*
Here is my code please Help me.
your Help will be greatly appreciated

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useDispatch } from 'react';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import "./carousel.css";
    // import axios from 'axios';
    import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    import { listProducts } from '../actions/productAction';
    
    
    
    export default function Home (props) {
    
        const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList);
        const { products, loading , error } = productList;
        const { dispatch } = useDispatch();
        useEffect(() => {
            dispatch(listProducts());
    
            return () => {
                //
            }
    
        }, [])
    
        return loading ? <div>loading...</div>:
        error ? <div>{error}</div>: 
        (
            <div id="myCarousel" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol className="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" className="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div className="carousel-inner">
                    <div className="carousel-item active">
                        <img className="first-slide" src="/images/image1.jpg" alt="First slide" />
                        <div className="container">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="carousel-item">
                        <img className="second-slide" src="/images/I2.jpg" alt="Second slide" />
                        <div className="container">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="carousel-item">
                        <img className="third-slide" src="/images/I3.jpg" alt="third slide" />
                        <div className="container">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a className="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a className="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
    
                
    
                <div className="container marketing">
                    {
                        products.map(product =>
                            <div className="row" key={product._id}>
                                <div className="col-lg-4">
                                    <div className="product">
                                        <img className="square-image" src={product.image} alt="{product.name}" width="140" height="140" />
                                        <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                                        <p>{product.description}</p>
                                        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                                    </div>
    
                                </div>
                            </div>)
                    }
    
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
    
        )
    }
```

PRODUCTACTION:-

```
import { PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS } from "../constants/productConstant";
import axios from 'axios';

const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {

    try {
        
        dispatch({ PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });
 
        const {data} = await axios.get ("/api/products");
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload : data});

        
    } catch (error) {
        
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload : error.message});
    }    
}

    export { listProducts }
```

Comment: can u update the question with the code here `../actions/productAction` as well?

Comment: can you include the stack trace?

Comment: Rukshan done bro..!!